# What is the format of string literal @ in yaml format?

Tags: ruby, yaml

I have a hash table of twitter users.

```
tweeter1: @jack
tweeter2: @jill
tweeter3: @john
```

But because of `@`, I can't `YAML.load` the file.

The error it throws is `Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): did not find expected node content while parsing a flow node at line 1 column 11`

How do you use string literal for `@` in YAML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just double quote your values:

```
tweeter1: "@jack"
tweeter2: "@jill"
tweeter3: "@john"
```

Then you should get the expected Hash when you read it:

```
{
    "tweeter1" => "@jack",
    "tweeter2" => "@jill",
    "tweeter3" => "@john"
}
```

You can always go to [yaml.org](http://yaml.org/) for details on the YAML format.

Answer (score 2):

You don't `YAML.load` files, you use `YAML.load_file`.

Otherwise, normally we can use a bare value for a string if it's not obviously an integer, but you can force it to a string by embedding it inside double-quotes:

```
tweeter1: "@jack"
tweeter2: "@jill"
tweeter3: "@john"
```

Something I do when I'm dealing with a YAML format problem, is create the structure in Ruby first, then let YAML create it for me, then use that as a model:

```
require 'yaml'

asdf = {
  'foo' => '@foo'
}

puts asdf.to_yaml
```

Outputs:

```
---
foo: ! '@foo'
```

Then, I'll do a round-trip test, which, if I get out what I put in, I'm happy:

```
pp YAML.load(asdf.to_yaml)
{"foo"=>"@foo"}
{
    "foo" => "@foo"
}
```

Notice though, `"@foo"` still works so, though YAML is using `! '@foo'`, it isn't necessary:

```
asdf = '
---
foo: "@foo"
'
YAML.load(asdf)
{
    "foo" => "@foo"
}
```

Comment: Didn't know about `load_file` method. That'll save me some lines of code. Thanks.